# File upload in Angular5

Tags: html, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to upload one or more than one files in my web application. 
I have tried with the code and error arising from vData.service.ts file

> Error: property 'yoursHeadersConfig' does not exist on VDataservice
>   property 'catchError' does not exist on 'observable'
>   property 'HandleError' does not exist on 'VDataservice'

Can you let me know how to resolve the issue and provide an idea for multiple file upload in the web application? I have provided entire relevant code for the issue.

Gist links:
ad.component.html: https://gist.github.com/aarivalagan/ac15e8e2c6f77d0687c01a70e18bca6b
ad:component.ts: https://gist.github.com/aarivalagan/a9c1d22c1d6056da624f0968fb6cd59c
vData.service.ts: https://gist.github.com/aarivalagan/8bfbe47ef8cf0dac267374a8f0ef5b0f

code:
ad.component.html

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <label for="usr">Choose file to Upload </label>
        <input type="file" multiple formControlName="file" class="form-control" id="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" accept=".pdf,.docx" required>
      </div>
```

ad.component.ts

```
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
        this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
    }
    uploadFileToActivity() {
        this.fileUploadService.postFile(this.fileToUpload).subscribe(data => {
          // do something, if upload success
          }, error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
```

vData.service.ts

```
postFile(fileToUpload: File): Observable<boolean> {
        const endpoint = 'your-destination-url';
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
        return this.http
          .post(endpoint, formData, { headers: this.yourHeadersConfig })
          .map(() => { return true; })
          .catchError((e) => this.handleError(e));
          }
```

Comment: The errors sum it up really, your VDataService does not a property called `this.yoursHeadersConfig`, nor `this.HandleError`. For the Observable error, which version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: @user184994...thanks for your reply...the version of rxjs which I am using is 5.5.6. Can you provide any suggestion for resolving the above three errors

Comment: @arar : did my answer work for you ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek....thanks for your help...it worked for me....sorry for the late reply

Comment: @arar no prob mate ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `catchError` use `pipe` operator

> property 'catchError' does not exist on 'observable'

```
  postFile(fileToUpload: File): Observable<boolean> {
    const endpoint = 'your-destination-url';
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    return this.http
      .post(endpoint, formData, { headers: this.yourHeadersConfig })
       .pipe(map(() => { return true; }),
             catchError((e) => this.handleError(e)));
   }
```

---

> Error: property 'yoursHeadersConfig' does not exist on VDataservice
>
> property 'HandleError' does not exist on 'VDataservice'

You havent defined these properties in `VDataservice`, so you can't call those methods using `this`.

You can try adding below method into `VDataservice` file:

```
HandleError(error){
   // write your logic to handle error here
}
```